# Cannot Obtain Similar DL Prediction Result in Pytorch C++ API Compared to Python

Tags: c++, machine-learning, deep-learning, computer-vision, pytorch

I have trained a deep learning model using unet architecture in order to segment the nuclei in python and pytorch. I would like to load this pretrained model and make prediction in C++. For this reason, I obtained trace file(with pt extension). Then, I have run this code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include <torch/script.h> // One-stop header.

#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>


using namespace cv;


int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {


    Mat image;
    image = imread("C:/Users/Sercan/PycharmProjects/samplepyTorch/test_2.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

    std::shared_ptr<torch::jit::script::Module> module = torch::jit::load("C:/Users/Sercan/PycharmProjects/samplepyTorch/epistroma_unet_best_model_trace.pt");
    module->to(torch::kCUDA);


    std::vector<int64_t> sizes = { 1, 3, image.rows, image.cols };
    torch::TensorOptions options(torch::ScalarType::Byte);
    torch::Tensor tensor_image = torch::from_blob(image.data, torch::IntList(sizes), options);
    tensor_image = tensor_image.toType(torch::kFloat);
    auto result = module->forward({ tensor_image.to(at::kCUDA) }).toTensor();


    result = result.squeeze().cpu();
    result = at::sigmoid(result);

    cv::Mat img_out(image.rows, image.cols, CV_32F, result.data<float>());

    cv::imwrite("img_out.png", img_out);

}
```

Image outputs ( First image: test image, Second image: Python prediction result, Third image: C++ prediction result):

[image]

As you see, C++ prediction output is not similar to python prediction output. Could you offer a solution to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though the question is old it might be useful to some. This answer is based on `pytorch 1.5.0` release (and first stable version of C++ frontend), the case might be a little different in previous versions (though `1.4.0`+ would work the same IIRC).

### PyTorch C++ frontend code

- no need to explicitly create `torch::TensorOptions` object if you only want to specify the type in `torch::from_blob`. Check [Configuring Properties of Tensor](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/notes/tensor_creation.html#configuring-properties-of-the-tensor) in PyTorch notes, this will clear it up further. Basically, you can just use `torch::ScalarType::Byte`.
- This type is equivalent to `torch::kUInt8` which is easier to find in the docs IMO
- No need to create `std::vector` object to keep shape as `torch::from_blob` has it's second argument of type `IntArrayRef`, which is a [`typedef`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typedef) for `ArrayRef<int64_t>` (see [`ArrayRef` documentation](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/classc10_1_1_array_ref.html#exhale-class-classc10-1-1-array-ref)). This class, in turn, has multiple overloaded constructors, one of which takes [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) (which is exactly yours `{ 1, 3, image.rows, image.cols }`)

With all that in mind you can create `tensor_image` in a single line like so (added `auto` as returned type is IMO obvious and `const` as it won't be modified further as the type is changed in the same line):

```
const auto tensor_image =
    torch::from_blob(image.data, {1, 3, image.rows, image.cols},
                     torch::kUInt8)
        .toType(torch::kFloat);
```

### Actual error

OpenCV loads images in `BGR` (blue-green-red) format, while PyTorch usually uses `RGB` (say in `torchvision` in `Python`). Solution is to permute your `image` so the colors match.

Including above change, whole code becomes:

```
const auto tensor_image =
    torch::from_blob(image.data, {1, 3, image.rows, image.cols},
                     torch::kUInt8)
        .toType(torch::kFloat)
        .permute(0, 3, 2, 1);
```

And you **should be** fine now with your predictions. Maybe it would be beneficial to get `tensor > 0` instead of `sigmoid` as it's probably binary classification and there is no need for this operation per se.

### Other PyTorch related stuff

There is no need to use `at` ([ATen](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/api/namespace_at.html#namespace-at) - as described in docs, foundational tensor and mathematical operation library on which all else is built) namespace anymore as `torch::` namespace redirects to it.

Clearer and less confusing options would be:

- `torch::kCUDA` instead of `at::kCUDA`
- `torch::sigmoid` instead of `at::sigmoid`

Also `.data<T>` is deprecated in favor of `.data_ptr<T>`

All in all you rarely need to use different namespace than `torch::` and it's sub-namespaces.

Comment: Yes, the actual error is related to the channel order. I obtained similar results after using permute function. Thanks for the detailed explanation.

Answer (score 1):

In the general case the output of unet is `(batch, classes, height, width)`, where `classes` refer to the segment class in your final mask. This means that each pixel has an associated vector of probabilities in dim `1`, which should be activated using `softmax` across this dimension, so that they sum to `1`. After that you can use `argmax` in the same dimension to obtain the most probable class for each pixel. In your case this would just be one of the two classes -- object or background.

If by any chance you were using FastAI to train your model, you can have a look [here](https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/34f3a32db5be43bdbcdc58a51610920136b1105f/fastai/basic_train.py#L114). This is a lookup which maps the activation function that should be used on the final layer based on the loss function used during training. Unet uses the `cross_entropy_loss` loss function.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, thanks for answering! Why do you think `softmax` is needed? It's binary image segmentation (as one can see by `matplotlib` output in the second image) which is binary. Tensor values greater than 0 (simple `tensor > 0`) might be better, but AFAIK `cv::Mat` constructor transforms `[0-1]` range into pixel values `[0-255]`.

Comment: Because OP is using unet which reduces segmentation to a classification problem. In binary segmentation there are two classes. `softmax` should be used so that the values in each pixel across all output layers sum to 1, as they are probabilities. After that, argmax will give the most probable class for each pixel (in this case object/background).

Comment: In binary segmentation you just have a `[0, 1]` mask. In case of two values `sigmoid` is a simplified version of `softmax`, in `PyTorch` it is used on single value. `sigmoid` also sums to `1` implicitly (only positive class have value (e.g. `0.3`), negative is equal to `1-0.3` in such case). This is done for each pixel. If you threshold `sigmoid` at `0.5` you get `binary mask` OP is after (or you can threshold `logits` without any activation at `0` for the same effect).

Comment: And I'm not sure what does it mean to reduce segmentation to classification problem. Segmentation is classification (can be binary or multiclass) but in the pixel domain as you said. If it was a multiclass case one would need tensor of shape `(batch, classes, width, height)`, in such case `softmax` (or simply `argmax`) along `1` dim would be fine. But his Python image displays `binary` classification, not multiclass one.

Comment: Unet gives exactly `(batch, classes, height, width)` output, for binary `(batch, 2, height, width)`.  I'm currently deploying this so this I know for sure. And FastAI is also using `softmax` for activation, unet is using cross-entropy-loss as loss function and FastAI maps it to `softmax` activation in https://github.com/fastai/fastai/blob/34f3a32db5be43bdbcdc58a51610920136b1105f/fastai/basic_train.py#L114, used in prediction. I'm saying exactly this, `softmax` along `1` dim. I was referring to OP's usage of `sigmoid` in `result = at::sigmoid(result);`.

Comment: Your `[0, 1]` looks like this because you have two classes -- object and background. I think we're saying the same thing here, maybe my wording is obscure.

Comment: UNet can give `(batch, 2, height, width)` for binary but it's wasteful memory-wise (twice the size of output). The same can be achieved with `(batch, height, width)` and thresholding / using `sigmoid`, see [this gist](https://git.io/JfYDf) for mask creation (you can put `softmax` and `sigmoid` there respectively). Version with `classes` is more general though. For binary case (as seems to be OPs case) if OP's network is implemented to output `(batch, width, height)` it is perfectly fine to use `sigmoid`.

Comment: About `fastai` I'm not sure how their `cross_entropy_loss` is implemented. Original PyTorch's [`torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#crossentropyloss) requires output from the neural network without activation due to stability reasons (combining `LogSoftmax` and negative log likelihood in one function). Analogously there is [`torch.nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#bcewithlogitsloss) working on unmodified outputs and combines `sigmoid` and `BCELoss` (once again, more numerically stable, hence advised).

Comment: OK, didn't know that, I'm working with the general implementation from FastAI. And just like you said *if* it's implemented in such way. I think you're right with the swapped image channels though and it's the case here, but in the general case using `sigmoid` for activation is incorrect and counter-intuitive. When I'm looking now at OP's code I think they're using `sigmoid` just to get the correct range in the output image and it doesn't have anything to do with result interpretation, but we would have to ask the OP :)

Comment: You might want to update your answer to reflect main points from this conversation about neural network's outputs so the overall image is clearer for future readers. Mine is already quite lengthy and I would give you an upvote in such case (and be at piece with question).